# How to convert UUID timestamp to ISO date Golang

Tags: go, uuid

I'm trying to use Google's library to generate a UUID for an event.
And now I need to filter the events by their time of creation.

```
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    id := uuid.New()
    fmt.Println(id.Time())
}
```

Output:

```
1118302296282601152
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It's not clear what results you're expecting from that code and why.

Comment: What's wrong with the `1118302296282601152` result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New** creates a new random UUID or panics. New is equivalent to the expression

**NewUUID** returns a Version 1 UUID based on the current NodeID and clock sequence, and the current time. If the NodeID has not been set by SetNodeID or SetNodeInterface then it will be set automatically. If the NodeID cannot be set NewUUID returns nil. If clock sequence has not been set by SetClockSequence then it will be set automatically. If GetTime fails to return the current NewUUID returns nil and an error.

So use the uuid.NewUUID() instead of New. This will give you the correct result.

```
id, _ := uuid.NewUUID()
t := id.Time()
sec, nsec := t.UnixTime()
timeStamp := time.Unix(sec, nsec)

fmt.Printf("Your unique id is: %s \n", id)
fmt.Printf("The id was generated at: %v \n", timeStamp)
```

Output:

```
    Your unique id is: 5bdf0fe4-0cc4-11ed-8978-025041000001 
    The id was generated at: 2022-07-26 14:51:41.2821988 +0530 IST
```

Comment: @MarisaRaj are you testing this in go playground?

Comment: @MarisaRaj please don't run this in playground. The date time is not accurate in the playground. Run this locally and let me know.. If still the issue persists then it could be related to your date time settings.

Comment: Your answer is missing critical bits of explanation: 1) The OP is generating v4 UUIDs which do not have time part encoded; 2) The need to actually read the docs on the `Time` method to understand why "1118302296282601152" gets printed.

Comment: @kostix you are right. I just edited my answer.

Comment: @Srikanth, yes I was. Forgive me, I ran it in VS Code and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @kostix, yes I will try to frame my question better. I'm new to the language. Thank you for  your inputs.